# Sql query. Nested or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I'm trying to list jr + sr students by their major but it's not working..

```
SELECT  
   Std_Major, 
   Std_Class, 
   AVG(Std_GPA)
FROM 
   Student 
WHERE 
   Std_Class LIKE 'JR%' AND Std_Class LIKE 'SR%'
GROUP BY 
   Std_Major, 
   Std_Class;
```

Comment: I think you want `or` instead of `and`.  No rows can possibly have a column that starts with both "JR" and "SR".

Comment: I think you're right but i wanted a combination of both jr and sr then group by major

Comment: yep, I go with @GordonLinoff you are saying std_class starts with JR and std_class start with SR too

Comment: is there a way to name the new combined row something else like "sr+ jr"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the **OR** operator instead of **AND**

Answer (score 2):

You must use **OR** in this case.

Example:

```
SELECT  Std_Major, Std_Class, AVG(Std_GPA)
FROM Student 
WHERE Std_Class LIKE 'JR%' OR Std_Class LIKE 'SR%'
GROUP BY Std_Major, Std_Class;
```

Answer (score 1):

Intead of

```
SELECT  Std_Major, Std_Class, AVG(Std_GPA)
FROM Student 
WHERE Std_Class LIKE 'JR%' AND Std_Class LIKE 'SR%'
GROUP BY Std_Major, Std_Class;
```

Use

```
SELECT  Std_Major, Std_Class, AVG(Std_GPA)
FROM Student 
WHERE Std_Class LIKE 'JR%' OR Std_Class LIKE 'SR%'
GROUP BY Std_Major, Std_Class;
```